# High voltage to motherboard from usb port

Tags: voltage, usb, high-voltage, hardware, motherboard

I am currently doing a research about the USB ports. What can be happened if we load high voltage to USB port. Which hardware parts will be damaged?

Comment: How can we know? That depends on the port hardware, and even with that info you can't really predict what will happen, only what *can* happen.

Comment: Can you better define your "high-voltage" source? Most ESD discharges by human bodies should be tolerable by USB ports.

Comment: It could destroy the entire motherboard.

Comment: If you want a proper answer, you will need to define what does "load" mean here? Does it mean connecting something with its own voltage supply into the +5V pin on the USB?  How could that happen? And what does "high-voltage" mean?  Do you mean some DC voltage higher than 5V? Do you mean mains power? Do you mean a static charge?  The answer to your question depends on these details.  To be sure there have been MANY USB ports which have been "bricked" by static discharge. And the kind of static discharge that you can't even see, hear or even feel.

Comment: So, is this a "research" project about hypothetical tolerance of USB ports, or something already did happen to your particular system?

Comment: 1st define Objective, sources and  limits by V, C , I ,R and pins. then do research on tolerance for V+ and mJ

Comment: Maybe you should search up the product USBKill.

Comment: I mean USB Kill, which parts will be burned if we plug USB KIll into port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hardware parts that are connected to the USB port will be damaged.

Typically, this is the "chipset", literally, the set of chips on the motherboard.  Specifically, the chip in the chipset that handles USB communications: the I/O controller hub.

Depending on the nature of the high voltage, it might be just the I/O controller hub, or also the passive components also connected to the USB port, the power supply, and the pcb wiring.

In practice, with realistic faults, sometimes it's just the I/O controller that stops working, and sometimes there's a burned spot on the motherboard.

Comment: Malicious high-voltage discharge into USB data lines can damage protective circuitry (clamping diode structures) on +5stb rail (where USB gets power), and create a crowbar on that rail. As result, nothing will start.